# Background for input field as processbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to realize a processbar inside an input field.
After sending the input with OK i want to transfer the field and show a short process bar.
I have not found any existing solution with jquery but if someone knows something...

This is my current solution whick works for scaling a 1px png.
http://jsfiddle.net/kaLbrg6w/

I would like to just define a fieldset like this without any other divs behind:

```
<fieldset>
    <input name="name" type="text">
</fieldset>
```

and just do the progressbar with css and js.
is there a better way, maybe without loading any images, to realize a progress bar and animate it?

*edit*
there is no js yet. the plan is to animate (fake like this: http://jsfiddle.net/kaLbrg6w/1/) the progress with the BG image width.
i also thought about adding a div behind or over the input field to animate it but i wanted to check for a solution where i dont have to use an extra element.

Comment: [**What have you tried**](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) so far, any jQuery code attempts to show? Btw, check out: [jQuery UI - progressbar](http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/)

Comment: you want to wrap the progress in a container of 500px like you have then the progress bar should be width of a % value, the JS will update the % of that loader DOM element.. What have you tried ?

Comment: How do you get the progress ? Do you want to fake it ?

Comment: i will fake the progress, just do an animation that takes 500ms or so. the BG width will be animated. but i dont see the problem to check for the progress and calculate the width of the BG or a div or a progress bar. i even could use a progress bar as an overlay of the input field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This jQuery will simulate a progress of 1100 ms, which will stay stuck almost at the end until the response from server came back.

```
    $('#myForm').on('submit', function(){
        $("#bar").show();
        var w = $('#bar').width() - 20;
        $('#progress').animate({ width: w }, 1000);
        $.post(YOURAJAX).success(function(r){
            $('#progress').animate({ width: w+20 }, 100);
            //code
        });
    });
```

with this kind of HTML :

```
<fieldset>
   <div id="bar">
      <div id="progress"></div>
   </div>
   <input name="name" type="text">
</fieldset>
```

And css :

```
#bar { display:none;width: 500px; position: relative; overflow: hidden; height: 20px;}
#progress {width: 0px; background-color: blue; height: 100%;}
```

This is just as an example of course.

Comment: yes i thought about that solution but in this case i will have to add Divs or write a JS which rewrites me the html and adds a progress bar to the element im using. which will work i think. i just wanted to know if there are other ways without adding divs but your solution works, thank you!

Comment: Happy to help, with css only you can use your fiddle's technique, but you will need JS in any case to get the progress and update the background-size, or at least add or remove classes. Please don't forget to accept the answer if you are done with this question :)

Comment: there is an example now for the animation of the background. the problem with the BG way is that i have to animate the position instead of the size. there is no way to animate just the width of the BG. maybe i will test the Div way too. http://jsfiddle.net/kaLbrg6w/1/ so what i understand is there is the Background way and the div way, which i can place before loading or while animating and remove the div afterwards. no other ways...

Comment: Well your fiddle looks good, why is it important for you to use the width instead of the position ?

Comment: Well you always have the _cursor_ way :). Add a `loading` class to `body` and add to your css `body.loading{cursor: wait}`.

Comment: it isnt important to animate the width. it was just the basic idea until i saw that it doesnt work. i like it how it works now :-)